# Hacking together an admin function for controller before_filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, authorization

I'm using Authologic and some written methods for managing users and what they can do in my app. I don't really need the ability to have multiple roles, I just need the ability for me to destroy things. I am wondering if I can hack this together.

In my "QuestionsController" I am using the following filters:

```
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]  # all actions require user to be logged in
  before_filter :init_data     # create a member variable called @post, initialized based on the action
  before_filter :require_owner, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] #edit, update, and destroy actions require ownership
```

I am trying to figure out if I can wrap those filters with a condition that specifies if the current_user's username is "bgadoci" then don't do the filters. Is this even possible and if so what syntax should I use (kind of new to ruby and rails).

Here is what I have now which is giving a syntax error in the first line (obviously).

```
  if :current_user :username => "bgadoci"
   before_filter :require_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]  # all actions require user to be logged in
   before_filter :init_data     # create a member variable called @post, initialized based on the action
   before_filter :require_owner, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] #edit, update, and destroy actions require ownership
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do a before filter that wraps those other filters?

```
before_filter :check_for_me


def check_for_me
  unless current_user.username == 'me'
    before_filter :require_user
    ..
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually that seemed to open up all the if you access a URL directly lik localhost:3000/questions/edit/1. So I guess that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: This actually worked if I wrapped the require_owner method in the application_controller (minus the def check_for_me part).

Comment: This is a scary answer. Before filter sets a filter on the class (not instance) level. In development, this won't be noticeable since the class is reloaded for every page load. However, in production once a single user who isn't 'you' hits the page, the filter will be enabled for everyone. What you really want is before_filter :require_user, :if => :name_of_func_that_returns_false_for_you, and then put another function on your controller.